# OpenWhisk - socket.io - client possible?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, openwhisk

I am trying to use socket.io from OpenWhisk action. I want to use it as a WebSocket client, but cannot seem to get it to work. Is socket.io client supported,
or is it only as server?

EDIT a client sample from http://socket.io/docs/

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io('ws://noderedjo2.mybluemix.net/ws/luftkvalitet/aqmeasure');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.send('hi');
});
```

This gives TypeError undefined is not a function. (on the io(...).

I guess one has to stand up a ws server, like in the Node.js samples on the same page...?!

Cheers
-jo2

Comment: The socket.io module is supported in an OpenWhisk action, can you paste example code of what you tried?

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I updated with a sample. I suspect I have started out wrong here...

Comment: A server is not supported in OpenWhisk as an action is shortlived. I'll try to work out an example. Meanwhile, check out socket.ios client API.

Comment: Thanks! I have read the socket.io client API. Running through the "io" variable, it seems to only have the "Server" function property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenWhisk currently does not support a websocket client library as part of the Node.js action containers. The packages currently supported are listed [here](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/reference.md#runtime-environment). I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/268) to add the most commonly used ones to this image as the use-case you laid out (running an OpenWhisk action and pushing to a websocket) sounds very useful.

[`socket.io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) itself only seems to be able to spin up a server, which is not suitable for an OpenWhisk action, as it is very short-running. [`socket.io-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) (I suggested to add that) is needed to connect to a Websocket server.

Comment: This sounds really great, thanks a lot! Looking forward to try it out when it is available :-)

Comment: Seems like socket.io-client is added now? https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/reference.md

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use webpack to include libraries not provided by the bluemix base install. See https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/openwhisk-webpack